# WPF Very Beginner Issue - Setting Default Control Values

Tags: wpf

Here is a very basic question from a WPF novice.
I have a form with some controls such as TextBoxes, DatePickers for example.
In a typical Windows Forms, I would set default values to these in onFormLoad event like

```
txtName.Text = "N/A";
dpStartDate.Value = DateTime.Now(5); //set 5 days from now
dpEndDate.Value = DateTime.Now(10); //set 10 days from now
```

How to do this in WPF form and where?  This is a very beginner question, where to do it the **right WPF-way**?

UPDATE:
So far, I have found that I can do this in Window_Loaded event like:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize Employee Data
    txtName.Text = "N/A";
    dpEmplDate.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100).Date.ToString();
    dpTermDate.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.ToString();
    txtAddress.Text = "N/A";
    dpDateOfBirth.Text = "";
    txtDepartment.Text="N/A";
    ...
    ...
}
```

So, I am setting default employee values like this.
My question is, is this proper WPF way to initialize data?
Thanks,

Comment: The answer to this question would be to learn WPF referring to [some tutorials](http://wpftutorial.net/LearnWPFin14Days.html). There are many possible answers to your question. You can do it in [code-behind or in xaml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970568%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @NirayDroshi Yes, I updated my question.  But I wonder if this is the right WPF way to do it.  Should it be done in Window_Loaded event?  Should I set defaults the way I am doing it in update or is there a proper WPF way?  Thanks

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend learning WPF using the MVVM pattern. It's a pretty serious departure from WinFroms, and will require you to think differently about a lot of things, but it is the way WPF was designed to work.  You will thank yourself later.

Comment: @BradleyUffner  That is what I want to do but can you give me some good starting example.  I thought MVVM is used only with ASP.NET so I did not read up on that.  Much appreciated.

Comment: ASP can use MVC, which is similar to MVVM, but they have slightly different implementations.

Comment: @dbnex14 [WPF with MVVM by Josh Smith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx?tduid=%289e4e15fb7ad56b4a1f64cce7969f8d16%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-f7rPiic5DAkEW0f0z5HKYg%29%28%29) is the first article I would suggest you to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no preferences to set values to `Controls` till you are not using [MVVM pattern.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx)

You can do it in XAML:

```
<TextBox Name=txtName Text="N/A"/>
```

or in code-behind:

```
txtName.Text = "N/A";
```

But WPF is very cool technology cause it can provide clean separation of concerns between data and view. It can be achieved using MVVM pattern.
It possible to use `Binding` to send data between data and view and from view to data. So in MVVM pattern data is set from `view model`. The example of syntax:

**View:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FooProperty}"/>>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    private string fooProperty="Hello World";        
    public string FooProperty
    {
        get { return fooProperty; }
        set { fooProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

`DataContext` property uses to connect `View` and `ViewModel`. Data from `ViewModel` will not be shown without setting `DataContext` property .

Comment: OK, that seems to be going closer where I want to go.  So in my updated question above, I would have to have a class called Employee which has properties set to default values and then I would use Binding in XAML like <TextBox Text="{Binding Employee.Name}"/> ??  Isn't that requiring class Employee to be static?  In your example, what if another class has property called FooProperty, how will {Binding FooProperty} know which FooProperty?  Much appreciated

Comment: Exactly!  The class doesn't need to be static though. You can use several different methods to instantiate the ViewModel class. You just have to get it in to the form's DataContext somehow.  An easy (but slightly frowned upon way) is to set it in the Form's constructor. `this.DataContext = New Employee()`.  Another option is to directly define it in the XAML, like this `<Form.DataContext><local:Employee/></Form.DataContext>`.  A better approach is to use something like MVVMLight to or a different framework to tie ViewModels to views and let it handle the plumbing.

Comment: @dbnex14 each `Control` has `DataContext` property. Consequently it is possible to set various `DataContext` with the same name of property. But it would be different view models. Read this article http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/

Comment: @StepUp Thank you so much, that article is very useful

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thank you so much Bradley

Comment: @dbnex14 you can sign my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of people

Comment: Please note that in my XAML example is should be `<Window.DataContext><local:Employee/></Window.DataContext>` instead of "Form.DataContext".  I've been switching between WinForms and WPF a lot lately and got mixed up.  It's passed the edit window for my original comment, so I can't fix it there.